# Resistance Order with a empty slot won't accept order. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: xcom-2, xcom-2-war-of-the-chosen

Here is a screenshot to explain the situation:
[image]

When I try to drag those available orders to the empty slot (red arrows) they won't move and make a bip sound like "can't do it".

There is no explanation why it won't accept. I don't know what to do.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Odd. I can't remember that being limited other than (I think) to orders from that faction, which seems to be just fine here.

Comment: I was so annoyed that I start to google everywhere... I just found [this discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xcom/comments/6yojth/most_op_resistance_order/) where the person wrote: _...so when the new month came around and I slotted that order..._  So, I guess I have to wait until the new month to allocate those orders. If that's the case, I will answer myself the question... Just need a month to pass to check if true or false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manage those orders only at the Supply Drop day.
Supply Drop day may happen at the end of the month, but I guess is not always:

[image: Supply drop day]

Comment: I'm resisting to mark this answer as correct because after the month turned, the game didn't offer or allow me to move the orders. So, I'm waiting for another month to see if it's a glitch or a bug.

Answer (score -1):

You can only change resistance orders during the monthly reports with the faceless commander (next time you get it, don't click through the screens quickly, stop and set your orders when that screen is presented).

[Here is a video](https://imgur.com/sZtBhiJ) for proof (first part of the video being allowed to edit orders during the monthly report and second part not being able to from the commander's quarters).

[image: Resistance monthly report]